# Compiling Google Web Toolkit project done in Eclipse with Hudson

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, hudson

I don't have much experience with Hudson, and have so far only used it with NetBeans.  However, I have created a Google Web Toolkit (GWT) project within Eclipse (I'm fairly new to both), and I want to use Hudson to automatically build the application.  Specifically, the way that I deploy the project now is to click the red icon on the top bar that says GWT Compile Project, then I right click on a file I wrote that builds a .war file and say Run As -> Ant Build, and then copy the .war file to the web server I'm using.  What I need to do is to do the GWT compile and .war building with Hudson, I already know how to run Windows commands to copy the file at the end of the compilation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the ant build does the GWT compile as well you can just create a Hudson project that calls the ant build.

Try doing a build from the command line only on a clean checkout without eclipse. Once that works... set up the same on Hudson.